# ios release build code signing not working

Tags: nativescript, codesign

I've installed the certificate and the provision.

I can see the cert in the Keychains app.

When I do a release build - I get a prompt

`codesign wants to sign using key 'my-key' in your keychain`

and a password prompt. I entered the password and no effect.

How can I change the password for the `login` keychain file - it doesn't seem to be hi-lighted.

Comment: It typically uses the system password. What you mean by it's not highlighted?

Comment: I mean the menu option `Change password for keychain login`. How can I set it to blank? why is the cli prompting me for the password? confused

Comment: As I already mentioned, login uses logged user's credentials. I'm afraid you can not change that alone without changing current users credentials.